# Can a bipartite graph contain nodes with no edges?

Tags: graph

For example, let us take two sets of nodes n1, n2 in left column and n3, n4 in the right column

Now there are edges between (n1,n3) and (n1,n4). Node n2 has no edges. Is such a graph bipartite graph ?

Comment: bipartite = two-colorable. What's your guess?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph

Comment: so, the above specified graph which has a node with no edges is a bipartite graph then ? (Since there are two independent sets of nodes and each edge has one end in left column and one end in right column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "Yes" as suggested by @Jan Dvorak in the comment above